# How to copy wine on pendrive?

Tags: wine

How to copy wine in pendrive and how to install it on other computer without internet connection? I want to install it on my friend's pc...

Answer (score 0):

Just download the .deb files.  You can get them [Here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+packages).  Once downloaded, you can save them to your pendrive.

You might also want to download winetricks.

You can also use synaptic, to generate a package download script.  If synaptic is not installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, run it, enter your password, and follow the screens below:

Search for Wine

[image]

Right click on the latest wine version, and click on Mark for Installation

[image]

This will mark wine, and all necessary dependencies, and get everything ready for installation.

[image]

Click on File, and choose Generate Package Download Script, and then save it to a location of your choice.

[image]

Navigate to where you've saved the file, and double click it, and then click on Run in Terminal.  This will start downloading all the files to the same folder.  Once all the files have been downloaded, go to terminal, and run the command:

```
Sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To download the package files you can go to either [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+packages) or by searching [Ubuntu package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), the first option will get the most up-to-date version, while the latter will give you the default one. It is up to you which option you will go with.

Note that you will need to download dependencies to the packages as well as the packages themselves, since your friend will have no way to get them oneself.

Once you have brought those packages to your friend's computer and placed them in some directory, go to that dir in the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This will install these packages (if everything is working).

Also, if you are planning to often perform such off-line installation process, you may wish to install apt-offline, which will then be able to generate on your friend's computer the signature of all the files to download, and then you can grab them on yours.

Of course, the initial install of apt-offline will need to be via the option discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Cube** in downloading wine packages in computer with internet connection and install it to an offline computer in later use.

Run cube in your friend's pc, then transfer the whole cube to a USB. Find a computer with internet connection and download wine on that (Windows or Linux). Then go back to the original computer to install downloaded packages.

You can download Cube and full tutorial at [Cube Launchpad Page](https://launchpad.net/camicricube)

[image: Download Wine1.6]

[image]